# Unstable long calculations

Tags: dafny

Trying to use Dafny as a CAS to check that some algebraic calculations are correct.
Dafny does a good job, except that it gets unstable for longer ones, failing to verify some very easy steps even when spoon-fed.

```
calc == {
  // a dozen lines...
  k * (a + b) * (a + b);
  k * (a * a + b * b + 2 * a * b); // fails
}
```

When Dafny fails there, I try to help it, in vain.

```
calc == {
  // a dozen lines...
  k * (a + b) * (a + b);
  calc == {
    (a + b) * (a + b);
    a * a + b * b + 2 * a * b;
  }
  k * (a * a + b * b + 2 * a * b); // still fails
}
```

I've also tried to put the substitued expression in a variable or even a lemma, with the same result.

Is there some way to tell Dafny which part of an expression we want to substitute?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem. What version of Dafny are you using?

Comment: In general, dealing with non-linear arithmetic (that is, variables multiplied by other variables) is unfortunately tricky and unstable. Since the 2.1.1 release of Dafny, I have improved the handling of non-linear arithmetic in Dafny (see the `/arith:1` check-in from April 3, if you're interested). You can get the improvement now if you're building Dafny from sources, and it will also be part of the next binary release. Curiously, even if I turn off the new improvement, your examples verify for me. (Btw, my Dafny is using Z3 version 4.5.0 - 64 bit, which is part of the Dafny release.)

Comment: I use the last releases of Dafny and Z3. What I meant is that I often get this kind of error ; Dafny succeds with this precise code but fails for larger examples. I'll open an issue the next time I run into it and twiddling `/arith` doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks. Again, it's difficult for the verifier to always get this right, but having your future examples of this will be great for the Dafny regression test suite.